# Print rows that has numbers in it

Tags: awk, sed

this is my data - i've more than 1000rows . how to get only the the rec's with numbers in it.

```
Records | Num

123 | 7 Y1 91

7834 | 7PQ34-102

AB12AC|87 BWE 67

5690278| 80505312

7ER| 998
```

Output has to be

```
7ER| 998

5690278| 80505312
```

I'm new to linux programming, any help would be highly useful to me. thanks all

Comment: *How to print only numbers from 2nd col in linux/unix?* - `7ER` is not in 2nd column

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest the title was misleading, so I changed it

Comment: `grep` solution : `grep -P '.+\s*?\|\s*\d+$'`, for column based filterning `awk` is the most suitable tool.

Comment: How are you columns separated? By pipes, or by spaces, or both?

Comment: @PS: More portable would be `grep '|[[:space:]]*[[:digit:]]\{1,\}$'`

Comment: it's pipe delimited

Comment: Sorry for the pain again! is there a way to get the count of the number of records that had non-numeric values for the above file

Comment: Thanks for the tip! This is how my data looks, To be clear, My 2nd col is Zip codes. I want to filter out only US zip codes which are 5 consecutive numbers. There are Canadian zip codes too in the data which are combination of  non-num & num. All the commands that you advised above works, but it is not ignoring such fields "87 BWE 67" .

Comment: just wanted to say hek2mgl a big thank you, and all who helped me here. i owe you all very much. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A short and simple GNU `awk` (`gawk`) script to filter lines with numbers in the second column (field), **assuming a one-word field** (e.g. `1234`, or `12AB`):

```
awk -F'|' '$2 ~ /\y[0-9]+\y/' file
```

We use the [GNU extension for regexp operators](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#gawk_002dSpecific-Regexp-Operators), i.e. `\y` for matching the word boundary. Other than that, pretty straightforward: we split fields on `|` and look for isolated digits in the second field.

**Edit:** Since the question has been updated, and now explicitly allows for **multiple words** in the second field (e.g. `12 AB`, `12-34`, `12 34`), to get lines **with numbers and separators only** in the second field:

```
awk -F'|' '$2 ~ /^[- 0-9]+$/' file
```

Alternatively, if we say only letters are forbidden in the second field, we can use:

```
awk -F'|' '$2 ~ /^[^a-zA-Z]+$/' file
```

Comment: thanks! have a problem, the 2nd col contains data like "87 BWE 67", which the above command is not ignoring. is there a way to get rid of this issue

Comment: I've updated the answer to reflect your revised and updated question. The second and third expressions will, f.e. filter out `12 aB 34`, but pass through `123-456`.

Comment: hello, how do i remove those fields from 2nd col in the same data which is not 5 consecutive numbers. Pl see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44892071/remove-all-fields-from-2nd-col-which-is-not-5-consecutive-numerical-digits

Comment: I answered you second question, take a look.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `awk`:

```
awk -F'[[:space:]]*[|][[:space:]]*' '$2 ~ /^[[:digit:]]+$/'
```

If you want to print the number of lines deleted as you've been asking in comments, you may use this:

```
awk -F'[[:space:]]*[|][[:space:]]*' '
    {
        if($2~/^[[:digit:]]+$/){print}else{c++}
    }
    END{printf "%d lines deleted\n", c}' file
```

Comment: Thanks for your Ans. I'm not getting any results for this . i need both the col in my output file and except "non-num" zipcodes.

Comment: Hi, I edited `$3` to `$2` hoping it would go to you for review and approval, but it turned out it is auto approved. Undo the change if you think otherwise.

Comment: Bravo! Absolutely Bravo. I'm very happy with  the right results followed  your solution. I'm so thankful to you. I really really wish all the best.So happy right now

Comment: @PS. `$2` will be the `|`.

Comment: @user71597 Glad to see that it helps

Comment: Sorry for the pain again! is there a way to get the count of the number of records that had non-numeric values for the above file

Comment: You want to print it at the end?

Comment: Yes! your soln gave me fresh file with all non-num files away. I wanted to know the count of records that  had non-num records which couldn't make it in

Comment: Seems like `$2` is more appropriate with `FS=\|`  (In the sample input, the line `7ER| 998` wants to match `$2`, but the line `7ER | 998` would match `$3`).  But perhaps `FS='[ |]*'` would be best.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Yep. Just realized that too. Let me change it.

Comment: Glad to see the conversation. Do i need to change anything from the above command that you've pasted?

Comment: @user71597: Probably easiest to subtract: `expr $(wc -l < original_file) - $(wc -l < new_file)`

Comment: awk -F'[[:space:]]*|[[:space:]]*' '$2 ~ /^[[:digit:]]+$/'  --- what is the use of this command. The soln that u gave me "awk -F"|" '$2 ~ /^[[:digit:]]+$/'"  has any problems?

Comment: The delimiter you are using is the `|`, optionally(!) surrounded by spaces. `-F'[[:space:]]*|[[:space:]]*'` describes that correctly and that is essential for the command to work correct.

Comment: got it! So which of these would work best 1- grep '|[[:space:]]*[[:digit:]]\{1,\}$' or 2-  
awk -F'[[:space:]]*|[[:space:]]*' '$2 ~ /^[[:digit:]]+$/' . The 1st command is giving me resutls, were as the 2nd one is just showing blanks. Pl advise

Comment: If you are sure the command runs only systems which have `gawk` installed, use the `gawk` version. Otherwise go with first version which is posixly correct and therefore portable.

Comment: Nvm. I've removed the `gawk` version.

Comment: I see a huge increase in the count of records when i used this command "sed -E '/^[^|]*\| *\b[0-9]+\b/!d' " . Using awk & grep gave the same record count but the above sed cmd is giving more records count

Comment: Hek - my 2nd col contains data like "7 Y1 91" , "87 BWE 67" , which the above commands are not omitting . i see my output file contain lots of non-num characters in there like this.

Comment: When your real data differs so much from the data you've showed in the question then edit your question. I can't guess it.

Comment: Thanks for the Tip Hek! Ive updated now. All the cmd's that you gave , are providing the right results except for values like "87 BWE 67" ,7PQ34-102 . Most of my real data are canadaian zip codes which is a combination of number & non-num which i want to get rid of. you've absoultely helpful to me.

Comment: The command is working correctly with that data. Probably you are using Windows line endings?

Comment: Pl have a look at this http://imgur.com/a/TKmbk . Not sure how this is doing. I tried it on a test data. I've to get this on production tomo....lil getting intimidated :(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44892071/remove-all-fields-from-2nd-col-which-is-not-5-consecutive-numerical-digits Pl look into this