# remove all fields from 2nd col which is not 5 consecutive numerical digits

Tags: awk, sed, grep

```
 Record | RegistrationID

 41-1|10551
 1-105|5569
  4-7|10043
  78-3|2176
   3-1|19826
   12-1|1981
```

Output file has to

```
 Record | RegistrationID
1-1|10551
3-1|19826
5-7|10043
```

My file is a **Pipe delimited**

any number in the 2nd col which is less than or more than 5lenght must be removed i.e only records that have 5 consecutive numbers must remain.I'm with google since an hour to fix this out any advice given would be highly appreciable. thanks in advance

tried this grep -E ' [0-9]{5}$|$' filename   - > not getting any results ,tx to cyrus

Comment: done !! Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: i'm a novice here, still finding lots of things new here in the world of programmers. Thanks for this tip. I've upvoted all those who have helped me. such a blessing this place is

Comment: Not just solutions, every single answer spun out by linux gurus gives me more courage and equal excitement to learn even more about linux. I never know how to reward people who added comments to my questions. Ill upvote all of em who helped me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this doesn't do what you want:

```
$ awk '(NR==1) || ($NF~/^[0-9]{5}$/)' file
 Acno | Zip
 high | 12345
tyty | 19812
```

then your real input file simply does not match the format that you provided in your example and you'd have to follow up on that yourself to figure out the difference and post more truly representative sample input if you want more help.

Given your updated input file with no spaces around the `|`s:

```
$ awk -F'|' '(NR==1) || ($NF~/^[0-9]{5}$/)' file
 Acno | Zip
 45775-1|10551
  2734455-7|10043
   167115-1|19826
```

If you REALLY have leading white space in your input that you want to remove from the output that's easily done but I'm going to assume for now that you actually don't really have that situation and it's just more mistakes in your posted sample input file.

With gawk 3.1.7 as the OP has (see comments below):

```
awk --re-interval -F'|' '(NR==1) || ($NF~/^[0-9]{5}$/)' file
```

Comment: when i executed the above awk command, i got a nw file with only headers in it. I will update the data above with one that i've here

Comment: i've updated with the real data sets that i got. Thx Ed

Comment: Add `-F\|` after `awk`, to specify the field delimiter. Then it should work.

Comment: It just occurred to me - one way the above could fail would be if you were running a really old, non-POSIX compliant awk that doesn't support regexp intervals (eg. `{5}`) so if it's still failing then tell us the awk version and shell you're using plus the platform you're running on.

Comment: GNU awk 3.1.7 . still the resulting file is empty

Comment: There you go then - you're using a version of gawk that's about 5 years out of date (we're now on gawk 4.1.4) and non-POSIX. Back then you had to add `--re-interval` to enable RE intervals. Get a modern version of gawk as you're missing a lot of bug fixes and extremely useful new functionality and meanwhile try running `awk --re-interval -F'|' '(NR==1) || ($NF~/^[0-9]{5}$/)' file`.

Comment: this works! thank you so much Ed. I've a doubt, does the above command removes all fields that are more than 5char from the 2nd col? how should i change this command to not let that happen. Only those fields from 2nd field whose length is less than 5 num's should be eliminated. those greater than 5 has to be in there. Sorry for the pain again Ed, i know i messed it up already

Comment: Your solution is just not an Answer, Ed! It gives me the inspiration to do alot of work around linux. Appreciate it! And Hey Stack, my life would have been bad if you didn't had this place on the internet with lots of talented linux penguins. lots of Love ! Ed Mortion , hello_god

Comment: Thank you. FYI `is just not` is a negative term which means `is not` but expressed more forcefully. I think based on the rest of your comment that you probably meant `is not just` which means `is more than`.

Comment: Absolutely No ! It's Perfect solution indeed it saved my day today.By "is not"  what i really meant is, Your answer opened me a new window of opportunities to know about linux more, and it's more than an answer could do .I was little overwhelmed suddenly when i got across a bunch of people who wished to help me for nothing. Just didn't know how to put it across :)

Answer (score 0):

If your columns (fields) are `|`-separated, may contain spaces, and the filtering criteria is exactly 5 digits in the second field, then try this:

```
awk -F'|' '$2 ~ /^[ ]*[0-9]{5}[ ]*$/' file
```

Additionally, to pass-through the header (first) line in addition:

```
awk -F'|' 'NR==1 || $2 ~ /^[ ]*[0-9]{5}[ ]*$/' file
```

Comment: hey Random! Is there a way to get rid of only those records that are lesser than 5chars , 5chars and > must be there in the file

Comment: Yes, check the [counted repetition `{min,max}`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/POSIX-Extended_Regular_Expressions) in Extended Regular Expressions. To select numbers with 5 digits at minimum, you can use `[0-9]{5,}`.

Answer (score -1):

Add --re-interval option to support the interval expression in the regular expression.

```
gawk --re-interval -F'|' '$NF~/^[0-9]{4,5}$/' file
```

Comment: hi. The above grep commands only filters out those records that are less than 5char or will it even delete those records that have more than 5chars?. I need only those rec's less than 5chars to go out of the file. the rest like 5char length and above length char are fine

Comment: gawk --re-interval -F'|' '$NF~/^[0-9]{5,}$/' file