# Linux file: File has 2 columns, Pipe delimited . I need to print the records from the 2nd col whose length is 5 or more chars

Tags: unix, awk, sed, grep

I just started learning awk and sed after my first 2 questions in stackOverflow. Thanks to Roman,Hek,Randomnir, Edmorton and many who corrected and helped me wholeheartedly. 
Right now i could do changes to awk commands to suit my data requirements. I just need some help from all out here.I'm taking baby steps to fix all unix errors on my own.Some advice will be helpful

My data -

```
ID | Passcode
41-1|10551
1-105|5569
 4-7|10043
 78-3|217631
  3-1|19826
 12-1|19818912
```

My output has to be

```
 ID | Passcode
41-1|10551
  4-7|10043
 78-3|217631
   3-1|19826
 12-1|19818912
```

All the records from the 2nd col which is less than 5char must be deleted or filtered . My o/p file should have only 5chars length or above Passcodes only.

Comment: Yet another duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44892071/remove-all-fields-from-2nd-col-which-is-not-5-consecutive-numerical-digits

Comment: I've closed that work. I've created this question on Ed's words. My previous question was about printing 2nd less than 5char, this question is contrary of that.

Comment: The difference between the two is a single `!`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty simple, just use the `length()` function to get words of length greater than or equal to `5` after setting the input and output field separators to `|`

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} NR==1 || length($2)>=5' file
```